# What Structure to Use for My Massive Database Tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I will keep this as short as possible. 
I am not looking for solutions but rather suggestions to designing a table for fast queries and easily updating specific sections of the table (counties).

I have a single table for each county in the USA. I want to somehow build a unified table such that I can query it and it will query all the county tables as well.

First thought was to use table inheritance. I have the parent table as the USA, with child tables as the states and then child tables of the counties. This method does not work since the query time is too long. I do not have any logical constraint to direct the Planner what child tables to query and which to skip.

I then though about using views. I created a view and union-ed all the counties together into one massive view. This still did not work and the queries took way to long.

I then decided to make a materialized view, but my computer crashed after 10 minutes in the attempts at querying such a large mat_view.

I then thought about creating a single unified table - but this does not allow me to update counties easily as they need.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this.
I am using Postgresql 9.6

Comment: The single table approach seems correct. All data that are specific to a county should be stored in a separate table, so that updates will only affect one row.

Comment: Any updates to the separate county tables will not have effect on the single table. I would need to rebuild it periodically to incorporate the updates. Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: Just to clarify: You have a separate table for each county (and county equivalent, since Alaska and Louisiana don't use the term counties) in the US? So that means, according to Wikipedia, you have 3,242 separate county tables. If that's the case, you're going to run into severe performance problems no matter how you cut it. Are you generating your queries/views programatically (I doubt you're writing a query that UNIONs 3,242 tables by hand). You need to normalize your data properly: Have 1 table that stores counties, linking a given county to the State.

Comment: Please post `CREATE TABLE` statements so we know what's going on.

Comment: @Zack that is what I have - I have a normalized list of over 3000 counties. I have a script that runs through all the county names and performs a `UNION`, `INHERIT`, `VIEW`, or `MATERIALIZED VIEW` depending on the method. I am not sitting here doing 3000+ manually. @Laurenz Albe I do not have access to the `CREATE TABLE` as they are already build from the company. I cannot edit the tables only copy them into new tables or new unions of tables.

Comment: Triggers might work, if you can add them to the individual county tables—that way, whenever something is modified in an individual county table, it also gets sent to your master table. You could also run a sync operation nightly.

Comment: You can reverse engineer `CREATE TABLE` statements with pgAdmin.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can you please tell me how?

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin myself, so I don't have one here. Alternatively, use `pg_dump -t <tablename> -s`.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. before continuing down a path to know the table format. Can you express why this matters? I am obviously willing to provide it if I can figure out how to get it, but I don't understand how knowing it will help the design.